# Filtering avoiding unexpected null using lambda's inline

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, nullpointerexception, nullable

I have list for each element I would like to do this (using Java 8):

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream().forEach(user -> usersRepository
                .findEnabledByUsername(user.getUserName()).setEnabled(false));
```

How ever `usersRepository.findEnabledByUsername` might return `null`.

Of course I can do this instead:

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream().forEach(user -> {
    UserEntity userEntity = usersRepository.findEnabledByUsername(user.getUserName()); 
    {
        if (userEntity != null) {
            userEntity.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

But I wonder if I could do the `null` check inline (in the first option)?

Comment: Did you consider the new type [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)? If something might return _null_, you better return an empty optional instead. Filtering on non-empty optionals is also very easy.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could do a mapping + filtering before running the `forEach` part, which also makes it a bit more readable:

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream()
            .map(user -> usersRepository.findEnabledByUsername(user.getUserName()))
            .filter(userEntity -> userEntity != null)
            .forEach(userEntity -> userEntity.setEnabled(false));
```

Or as an alternative:

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream()
            .map(User::getUsername)
            .map(usersRepository::findEnabledByUsername)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(userEntity -> userEntity.setEnabled(false));
```

Comment: One more thing. if in the last line - in the the foreach clauses ill want to do more logic how can you modify it? let's say after setEnable I want to send each userEntity to method doSomething().

Comment: `.forEach(userEntity -> { userEntity.setEnabled(false); soSomething(userEntity); });`

Answer (score 7):

Some alternatives to the @assylias [answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24779909/1594933).

Use a method reference to [Objects==nonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) for the `null` check:

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream()
    .map(User::getUsername)
    .map(usersRepository::findEnabledByUsername)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(userEntity -> userEntity.setEnabled(false));
```

---

if you can update `UserEntity` with a `disable` method

```
class UserEntity {
    public void disable() {
        setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

you can again use a method reference (`UserEntity::disable`) :

```
disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream()
    .map(User::getUsername)
    .map(usersRepository::findEnabledByUsername)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(UserEntity::disable);
```

---

Some resources:

- [Method References on the java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)
- [JSR 335: Lambda Expressions for the JavaTM Programming Language](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335)

Comment: And if I would like to add to the last forEach another method call. how would you combine that in?

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: disabledUsersOnLDAP.stream()
            .map(UserLdap::getUserName)
            .map(usersRepository::findEnabledByUsername)
            .filter(userEntity -> userEntity != null)
            .forEach(userEntity -> {
                userEntity.disable();
                cleanUserTicket(userEntity.getUsername());
            });

Comment: @rayman Ok. Unless you have a specific method doing all this stuff you can't use a method reference. It is important to note that this method is not necessarily on UserEntity ; it could be a static method or a method of an accessible object. The advantage of using method reference is that you reference a named method, the intention is more clear.